# Java: Generic array creation error?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Getting a Generic array creation error on a non generic array, I think?

So, this code works fine, pretty straight-forward.

```
public class test {
  private subTest[] subTests;
  private class subTest {

  }

  public test(int size) {
    subTests = new subTest[size];
  }
}
```

But what I am actually trying to do is something more like this:

```
public class test<T> {
  private subTest[] subTests;
  private T[] arrayOfGenerics; 

  private class subTest {

  }

  public test(int size, int size2) {
    arrayOfGenerics = (T[]) new Object[size];   //This line works fine
    subTests = new subTest[size2];              //This line is the one giving me a 'Generic array creation' error
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subTest` is an inner class of `test`, so the type parameter of `test` is visible from within `subTest`. Therefore, you are trying to create an array of generic type

```
test<T>.subTest[]
```

You can solve this by making the class `subTest` a static nested class instead:

```
private static class subTest
```

If you do this, the type of the array is just

```
test.subTest[]
```